# Python send enter Key over telnet

Tags: python-2.7, key, enter, secure-crt

i'm not able to send "enter" key for  after accessing the access server, i need to type the device name and hit enter ... till here its working .... after this .. i need to send another enter key .. looks like my script new line but not the enter key

```
objNewTab = crt.Session.ConnectInTab("/TELNET 192.168.0.13 23")

      if objNewTab.Session.Connected:
        objNewTab.Screen.Synchronous = True
        objNewTab.Screen.WaitForString("sername:")
        #objNewTab.Screen.Send(user1 + "\r")
        #objNewTab.Screen.Send(password + "\r")
        #objNewTab.Screen.Send("csessionisco" + "\r")
        #objNewTab.Screen.Send("cisco" + session + "\r")
        #objNewTab.Screen.Send("rsrack" + rackNumber + session + "\r")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send(user1 + "\r")
        objNewTab.Screen.WaitForString("assword:")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send(password + "\r")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("\r")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("\r")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("\r\n")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("\n")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("\n\r")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send(session)  
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("\r")   /// i need to send enter after this line ...
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("\n\r")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("\r\n")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("\r")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("\r")
        #objNewTab.creen.sendKeys("[enter]")
        #objNewTab.Screen.Send(VbCr)
        #objNewTab.Screen.Send chr(13)
        objNewTab.Screen.Send(chr(13))
        objNewTab.Screen.Send('{ENTER}')
        objNewTab.Screen.Send(chr(13))
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("{ASC 065}")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send('{ASC 2709}')
        objNewTab.Screen.Send('{ASC 2709}')
        objNewTab.Screen.Send('{ASC 2709}')
        objNewTab.Screen.Send('{ASC 2709}')
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("{ASC 065}")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("{ASC 065}")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("{ASC 065}")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("{ASC 065}")
        objNewTab.Screen.Send(chr(13))
        objNewTab.Screen.Send(chr(13))
        objNewTab.Screen.Send("\r")
```

...it shows that its sending new line . but not the enter KEY:

```
Username: 

User Access Verification

Username: kha.ismael
Password:                                                                                              



PDX-03#
PDX-03#R4
Translating "R4"
Trying asa4 address #1 ... Open










<pre>
```

while it should send the enter KEY and i need to be like this :

```
Username: 

User Access Verification

Username: kha.ismael
Password:                                                                                              




PDX-03#
PDX-03#R4
Translating "R4"
Trying asa4 address #1 ... Open






R4>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i just send a sleep command  or to be more accurate i configure WaitForString for any character  with timeout value (1000 mil sec )  in between and that resolved the issue.